# How to put two (or multiple) QED symbols on one line

Tags: spacing, amsthm

Suppose the proof of a theorem contains a claim and its proof, and the proof of the claim completes the proof of the theorem.  That is, no further text is required in the proof of the theorem after the end of the proof of the claim.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Today is Thursday.

\begin{proof}
We know that the day after Wednesday is always Thursday.
Thus the theorem follows from the following claim:

\begin{claim}
Yesterday was Wednesday.

\begin{proof}
My computer said so.
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

By default the second QED symbol is placed a line below the first, even though there is no text on that line.  It would seem more natural to place both QED symbols on the same line, next to each other, to indicate that the two (nested) proofs both conclude at that point.  How can we achieve this?  I've tried inserting the `\qedhere` command but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4):

double the `\qedsymbol`.

in the preamble,

```
\let\oldqedbox\qedsymbol
\newcommand{\twoqedbox}{\oldqedbox\oldqedbox}
```

then, before the first `\end{proof}`, insert

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\twoqedbox}
```

and before the second `\end{proof}`, insert

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
```

a "renewed" `\qedsymbol` will not persist.

`amsthm` was not designed to handle nested proofs; they are very rare.

Comment: But there's still the trailing QED box from the outer proof that shouldn't appear.  I don't want an _extra_ box, I want to _move_ the box from the outer proof so that it appears together with the previous box.  If you've doubled the box for the inside proof, we need to remove the one from the outer proof.

Comment: Furthermore, I was hoping for an automatic solution - something we can change in the preamble so that this will happen automatically every time there are two (or more) nested `end{proof}`s with no text in between.

Answer (score 2):

You can fake the proof environment.

```
\begin{theorem}
Today is Thursday.
\end{theorem}  % moved to here

\begin{proof}
We know that the day after Wednesday is always Thursday.
Thus the theorem follows from the following claim:
\begin{claim}
Yesterday was Wednesday.
\end{claim}
\noindent\textit{\proofname.} My computer said so.\qedhere\qedsymbol
\end{proof}
```

[image]